# value of radio button and option menu value in Tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

```
def fresh():
 t = Toplevel()
 t.geometry("%dx%d%+d%+d" % (600, 400, 0, 0))

 rad1 = StringVar(t)
 opt1 = StringVar(t)
 opt1.set("School Board")
 opt2 = StringVar(t)
 opt2.set("Department")

 form = Frame(t)
 form.pack()
 for (ix, label) in enumerate(fieldnames):
  lab = Label(form, text=label)
  ent = Entry(form)
  lab.grid(row=ix, column=0)
  ent.grid(row=ix, column=1)
  entries[label] = ent

 r1=Radiobutton(form, text="M", variable=rad1, value="M")
 r1.grid(row=5,column=0)


 r2 = Radiobutton(form, text="F", variable=rad1, value="F")
 r2.grid(row=5, column=1)
 student.gender = rad1.get()
 l = OptionMenu(form, opt1, "CBSE", "State Board","SB-TN","SB-KA","SB-KL","SB-AP","SB-RJ","SB-MH" )
 l.grid(row=6, column=1)
 student.SB = opt1.get()
 l2 = OptionMenu(form, opt2,"AE","CH","CI","CSE","ECE","EEE","EIE","ME" )
 l2.grid(row=7, column=1)
 student.dept = opt2.get()
```

The value for radio button remains NULL value.

opt1 and opt2 value is also not getting changed other than default value.

kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're changing, you're just not tracing the change. When you're setting them with these lines:

```
student.gender = rad1.get()
```

it's only getting set when the control flow passes over them. So, those values are going to be the values on initiation of the code.

You can trace a variable class instance with the [`trace`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) method. Here's a small example:

```
root = Tk()

def callback(*args): # function called when var changes
    print var.get()  # this is where you'd set another variable to var.get()

var = StringVar()

Radiobutton(root, text='M', variable=var, value='M').pack()
Radiobutton(root, text='F', variable=var, value='F').pack()

var.trace('w', callback) # this will call a function when var changes

mainloop()
```

Alternatively, you can set a `command` to a callback in the Radiobutton options. Or, if you don't need the values updated in real-time, you could make a button that handles all of the processing of the fields at once.